# Illegal Self Reference

Tags: java, android-studio

I am writing an android app that uses a bundle to pass data between activities. I made an Answers.java class to get the data from the bundle. When I try to get the data I receive an error **Illegal Self-Reference**. I get the error on

```
 Answers a = a.getQuestion1_1();
```

Here is my activity code

```
    package www.iup.edu.iupcrimsurvey;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Thank_You_MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Answers a = a.getQuestion1_1();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thank__you__main);

    // Sets an onClickListener to the button and calls the launchNextScreenActivity() method
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next_Screen15);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchNextScreenActivity();
        }
    });

    // Sets an onClickListener to the button and calls the launchNextScreenActivity() method
    final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Close);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchFinishActivity();
        }
    });
}

// Switches to the StartScreen_Activity screen
private void launchNextScreenActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartScreen_MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Closes the app
private void launchFinishActivity() {

}
```

}

My Answers.java file

```
     package www.iup.edu.iupcrimsurvey;

    public class Answers {
        private int question1_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getInt("Demographics_question1");
        private String question1_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Demographics_question2");
        private String question1_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Demographics_question3");
        private String question1_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Demographics_question4");
        private String question1_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Demographics_question5");
        private String question1_6 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Demographics_question6");
        private String question1_7= StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Demographics_question7");

private String question2_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("housing_question1");
private int question2_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getInt("housing_question2");
private String question2_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("housing_question3");
private String question2_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("housing_question4");

private String question3_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Sexuality_question1");
private String question3_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Sexuality_question2");
private String question3_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Sexuality_question3");
private String question3_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Sexuality_question4");
private String question3_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Sexuality_question5");

private String question4_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Alcohol_question1");
private String question4_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Alcohol_question2");
private String question4_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Alcohol_question3");
private String question4_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Alcohol_question4");
private String question4_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Alcohol_question5");

private String question5_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Travel_question1");
private String question5_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Travel_question2");
private String question5_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Travel_question3");
private String question5_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Travel_question4");
private String question5_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Travel_question5");

private String question6_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Work_question1");
private String question6_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Work_question2");
private String question6_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Work_question3");
private String question6_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Work_question4");
private String question6_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Work_question5");



private String question7_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Crime_question1");

private String question8_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Crime_Committed_question1");
private String question8_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Crime_Committed_question2");
private String question10_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question1");
private String question10_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question2");
private String question10_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question3");
private String question10_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question4");
private String question10_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question5");
private String question10_6 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question6");
private String question10_7 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question7");
private String question10_8 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question8");
private String question10_9 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question9");
private String question10_10 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Incident_question10");

public int getQuestion1_1() {
    return question1_1;
}

public void setQuestion1_1(int question1_1) {
    this.question1_1 = question1_1;
}

public String getQuestion1_2() {
    return question1_2;
}

public void setQuestion1_2(String question1_2) {
    this.question1_2 = question1_2;
}

public String getQuestion1_3() {
    return question1_3;
}

public void setQuestion1_3(String question1_3) {
    this.question1_3 = question1_3;
}

public String getQuestion1_4() {
    return question1_4;
}

public void setQuestion1_4(String question1_4) {
    this.question1_4 = question1_4;
}

public String getQuestion1_5() {
    return question1_5;
}

public void setQuestion1_5(String question1_5) {
    this.question1_5 = question1_5;
}

public String getQuestion1_6() {
    return question1_6;
}

public void setQuestion1_6(String question1_6) {
    this.question1_6 = question1_6;
}

public String getQuestion1_7() {
    return question1_7;
}

public void setQuestion1_7(String question1_7) {
    this.question1_7 = question1_7;
}

public String getQuestion2_1() {
    return question2_1;
}

public void setQuestion2_1(String question2_1) {
    this.question2_1 = question2_1;
}

public int getQuestion2_2() {
    return question2_2;
}

public void setQuestion2_2(int question2_2) {
    this.question2_2 = question2_2;
}

public String getQuestion2_3() {
    return question2_3;
}

public void setQuestion2_3(String question2_3) {
    this.question2_3 = question2_3;
}

public String getQuestion2_4() {
    return question2_4;
}

public void setQuestion2_4(String question2_4) {
    this.question2_4 = question2_4;
}

public String getQuestion3_1() {
    return question3_1;
}

public void setQuestion3_1(String question3_1) {
    this.question3_1 = question3_1;
}

public String getQuestion3_2() {
    return question3_2;
}

public void setQuestion3_2(String question3_2) {
    this.question3_2 = question3_2;
}

public String getQuestion3_3() {
    return question3_3;
}

public void setQuestion3_3(String question3_3) {
    this.question3_3 = question3_3;
}

public String getQuestion3_4() {
    return question3_4;
}

public void setQuestion3_4(String question3_4) {
    this.question3_4 = question3_4;
}

public String getQuestion3_5() {
    return question3_5;
}

public void setQuestion3_5(String question3_5) {
    this.question3_5 = question3_5;
}

public String getQuestion4_1() {
    return question4_1;
}

public void setQuestion4_1(String question4_1) {
    this.question4_1 = question4_1;
}

public String getQuestion4_2() {
    return question4_2;
}

public void setQuestion4_2(String question4_2) {
    this.question4_2 = question4_2;
}

public String getQuestion4_3() {
    return question4_3;
}

public void setQuestion4_3(String question4_3) {
    this.question4_3 = question4_3;
}

public String getQuestion4_4() {
    return question4_4;
}

public void setQuestion4_4(String question4_4) {
    this.question4_4 = question4_4;
}

public String getQuestion4_5() {
    return question4_5;
}

public void setQuestion4_5(String question4_5) {
    this.question4_5 = question4_5;
}

public String getQuestion5_1() {
    return question5_1;
}

public void setQuestion5_1(String question5_1) {
    this.question5_1 = question5_1;
}

public String getQuestion5_2() {
    return question5_2;
}

public void setQuestion5_2(String question5_2) {
    this.question5_2 = question5_2;
}

public String getQuestion5_3() {
    return question5_3;
}

public void setQuestion5_3(String question5_3) {
    this.question5_3 = question5_3;
}

public String getQuestion5_4() {
    return question5_4;
}

public void setQuestion5_4(String question5_4) {
    this.question5_4 = question5_4;
}

public String getQuestion5_5() {
    return question5_5;
}

public void setQuestion5_5(String question5_5) {
    this.question5_5 = question5_5;
}

public String getQuestion6_1() {
    return question6_1;
}

public void setQuestion6_1(String question6_1) {
    this.question6_1 = question6_1;
}

public String getQuestion6_2() {
    return question6_2;
}

public void setQuestion6_2(String question6_2) {
    this.question6_2 = question6_2;
}

public String getQuestion6_3() {
    return question6_3;
}

public void setQuestion6_3(String question6_3) {
    this.question6_3 = question6_3;
}

public String getQuestion6_4() {
    return question6_4;
}

public void setQuestion6_4(String question6_4) {
    this.question6_4 = question6_4;
}

public String getQuestion6_5() {
    return question6_5;
}

public void setQuestion6_5(String question6_5) {
    this.question6_5 = question6_5;
}

public String getQuestion7_1() {
    return question7_1;
}

public void setQuestion7_1(String question7_1) {
    this.question7_1 = question7_1;
}

public String getQuestion8_1() {
    return question8_1;
}

public void setQuestion8_1(String question8_1) {
    this.question8_1 = question8_1;
}

public String getQuestion8_2() {
    return question8_2;
}

public void setQuestion8_2(String question8_2) {
    this.question8_2 = question8_2;
}

public String getQuestion10_1() {
    return question10_1;
}

public void setQuestion10_1(String question10_1) {
    this.question10_1 = question10_1;
}

public String getQuestion10_2() {
    return question10_2;
}

public void setQuestion10_2(String question10_2) {
    this.question10_2 = question10_2;
}

public String getQuestion10_3() {
    return question10_3;
}

public void setQuestion10_3(String question10_3) {
    this.question10_3 = question10_3;
}

public String getQuestion10_4() {
    return question10_4;
}

public void setQuestion10_4(String question10_4) {
    this.question10_4 = question10_4;
}

public String getQuestion10_5() {
    return question10_5;
}

public void setQuestion10_5(String question10_5) {
    this.question10_5 = question10_5;
}

public String getQuestion10_6() {
    return question10_6;
}

public void setQuestion10_6(String question10_6) {
    this.question10_6 = question10_6;
}

public String getQuestion10_7() {
    return question10_7;
}

public void setQuestion10_7(String question10_7) {
    this.question10_7 = question10_7;
}

public String getQuestion10_8() {
    return question10_8;
}

public void setQuestion10_8(String question10_8) {
    this.question10_8 = question10_8;
}

public String getQuestion10_9() {
    return question10_9;
}

public void setQuestion10_9(String question10_9) {
    this.question10_9 = question10_9;
}

public String getQuestion10_10() {
    return question10_10;
}

public void setQuestion10_10(String question10_10) {
    this.question10_10 = question10_10;
}

public String getQuestion11_1() {
    return question11_1;
}

public void setQuestion11_1(String question11_1) {
    this.question11_1 = question11_1;
}

public String getQuestion11_2() {
    return question11_2;
}

public void setQuestion11_2(String question11_2) {
    this.question11_2 = question11_2;
}

public String getQuestion11_3() {
    return question11_3;
}

public void setQuestion11_3(String question11_3) {
    this.question11_3 = question11_3;
}

public String getQuestion11_4() {
    return question11_4;
}

public void setQuestion11_4(String question11_4) {
    this.question11_4 = question11_4;
}

public String getQuestion11_5() {
    return question11_5;
}

public void setQuestion11_5(String question11_5) {
    this.question11_5 = question11_5;
}

public String getQuestion11_6() {
    return question11_6;
}

public void setQuestion11_6(String question11_6) {
    this.question11_6 = question11_6;
}

public String getQuestion11_7() {
    return question11_7;
}

public void setQuestion11_7(String question11_7) {
    this.question11_7 = question11_7;
}

public String getQuestion11_8() {
    return question11_8;
}

public void setQuestion11_8(String question11_8) {
    this.question11_8 = question11_8;
}

public String getQuestion11_9() {
    return question11_9;
}

public void setQuestion11_9(String question11_9) {
    this.question11_9 = question11_9;
}

public String getQuestion11_10() {
    return question11_10;
}

public void setQuestion11_10(String question11_10) {
    this.question11_10 = question11_10;
}

private String question11_1 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question1");
private String question11_2 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question2");
private String question11_3 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question3");
private String question11_4 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question4");
private String question11_5 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question5");
private String question11_6 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question6");
private String question11_7 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question7");
private String question11_8 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question8");
private String question11_9 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question9");
private String question11_10 = StartScreen_MainActivity.MyAppsBundle.getString("Relationship_question10");
```

}

Comment: You need to _instantiate_ the `Answers` `a` object somewhere.  How do you plan to create this object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are trying to call is wrong.
Please follow this:
Create the Object of the Answer class

```
> public class Thank_You_MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Answer a;//Create an object

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_thank__you__main);
        a = new Ans();//define it
        String aa = a.getGetQuestion1_1();  then use it anywhere
```

Hope this will help you